# typescript array sorting with random sort order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, typescript

I want to sort an array based on an sort order.

```
public array1: Array<string> = [];
array.push(some string values); //E.g dog,apple,man
```

I have a sort order like

- dog = 1
- apple = 3
- man = 2

So i want to sort this array like dog,man,apple.

How to do this in typescript.

Comment: Can you show me your full array with values? then only we can sort the order.\

Comment: Array values are random.

Comment: just so I can get this straight, you want to randomly shuffle a list?

Comment: alphas = ["dog","apple","man"] ;

Comment: randomly is fine. But the items having any sorting number?

Comment: yes shuffle the list based on the sort order mentioned above.

Comment: yes. They have a sorting number.

Comment: how do you get your sort order?

Comment: where is the sorting number in your array `["dog","apple","man"] ;`??

Comment: i get the array values from service and sort order from content based on the array values

Comment: You have wrong understanding of Typescript because it is just Javascript with types, instead you should google it like "array sort in javascript"

Answer (score 3):

If you'd have your order in a map(object) you could just do this.

```js
let list = ['dog', 'cat','apple'];
let sortOrder = {
    dog: 1,
    cat: 3,
    apple: 2
}

list.sort((a, b) => sortOrder[a] - sortOrder[b]);
```

You can see a working playground example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20list%20%3D%20%5B'dog'%2C%20'cat'%2C'apple'%5D%3B%0D%0Alet%20sortOrder%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dog%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cat%3A%203%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20apple%3A%202%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alist.sort((a%2C%20b)%20%3D%3E%20sortOrder%5Ba%5D%20-%20sortOrder%5Bb%5D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(list)%3B).

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you use TypeScript (as tagged in you question).

```
let data = [
   {value:"dog", key:1},
   {value:"apple", key:3},
   {value:"man", key:2},
];

data.sort((d1, d2) => {
  if (d1.key > d2.key) return 1;
  if (d1.key < d2.key) return -1;
  return 0;
});
```

You have enhanced your question then this answer is not relevant anymore (and fixed code as mentioned in comments).

Comment: if i declare an array like    public arrayName: Array<{key: string, value:string}> = [];  then its throwing error data.sort(d1,d2)=>(d1, d2) => {}

Comment: Yes, the code has typos.  Remove the first instance of the text `d1,d2)=>` and add `);` to the very end.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25984542/4463445).

```
randomizeArray(a, b, c, d) { // array, placeholder, placeholder, placeholder
    c = a.length; while (c) b = Math.random() * c-- | 0, d = a[c], a[c] = a[b], a[b] = d
}
```

And you can call this function this way, where `data` is an array `[]`

```
this.randomizeArray(data, null, null, null);
```